# Parse.com iOS localDatastore only pinning, not finding objects after enabling. (Can't unpin since it can't find objects, either)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I updated to latest parse SDK 1.6.2 to take advantage of localDatastore.  Unfortunately, I cannot retrieve pinned objects.  Simplest implementation:

```
- (void)queryForPinning{
if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil){
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GolfScores"];
    [query whereKey:@"golferId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (!error){
            [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
                if (succeeded){
                    NSLog(@"count %lu", (long unsigned)objects.count);
                }
            }];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}}

- (void)queryLocalData{
if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil)
{
    PFQuery *localQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GolfScores"];
    [localQuery whereKey:@"golferId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [localQuery fromLocalDatastore];
    [localQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"hopefully found this many objects %lu", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"something went wrong");
        }
    }];
}}
```

The first query for pinning is called, and completes.  It logs to the console in the block and if I add code to update a tableview it does that successfully.  I have confirmed it is actually pinning the objects as shown in the edit at the end of this post.  The second query, requesting from localDatastore, logs 0 objects found by the query.

When I do these queries from the network, it works correctly.

As I understand, the steps to get localDatastore to work are: Enable it in appDelegate, pin the objects, query the objects with [query fromLocalDatastore] so the query knows to look locally.  If I missed a step please advise.

I'll mention if I use the alternate syntax using BFTask as found in iOS docs like thus I get the "BFTask is a Forward Declaration" error:

```
[[localQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YE"] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task{
  if (task.error) {
// Something went wrong.
return task;
  }
  // task.result will be your game score
  return task;
}];
```

I've seen the BFTask/Forward Declaration question answered on stack overflow, and the answer was to include CoreData.  I have the CoreData framework, and I've tried explicitly including CoreData/CoreData.h (but that didn't work, so I removed the explicit include line and I'm not using BFTask anyway).  I'm just offering this as a clue that may suggest I've done something wrong in case the answer is non-obvious.  If this is not a clue but a distraction, please ignore.

I apologize about the trivial question that is seemingly answered by documentation itself.  Please ignore any trivial syntax errors as I had trouble getting the text box to recognize my nested style.

My method for testing the pinned objects has been to run an iOS device and read the console logs.  The query to pin the objects is called by a pull to refresh.  The local query is called on viewWillAppear.  I would run the first query, get a successful log in the console, then stop and run the application again and go to the view to trigger the local query which would result in a count of 0.  I also tried similarly without rerunning the app while connected to xCode and just ran it on the device itself.  Similarly, no result (I would update a tableview if there were a result, since I couldn't read a console log in this manner - the tableview would update from the network but not from the local query).

Thanks for reading.

Edit:  I have confirmed my objects are being pinned by downloading the app container, changing the .xcappdata extension to .xml, and navigating to AppData>Library>Private Documents>Parse>ParseOfflineStore.  Therefore, it should just be a matter of querying the objects. (Note: be careful you are not saving anything to the store that would make it that much easier for a hacker to get harmful data)

Double Edit: Using the information in the edit above, I can also confirm that unpin isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your query code looks correct, so I think it's a problem with when the queries are started. Make sure that the second query is started *only* after the first is done pining objects to the LDS.

I also recommend that you start naming your pins and in the first query you unpin all previous data before pining the new data ([something like this](https://gist.github.com/lightice11/9b375cc50c8c7c6f32f9)).

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.  I've done my best to confirm it's not a timing issue, but I agree with your other suggestions.  I'll update the topic title to reflect that unpinning isn't working, either.  To anyone else who may encounter this problem and reads this thread, I apologize but I'm moving on from using localDatastore.  I don't know the etiquette of whether I should have this topic nuked or if the information should stand as it may help someone else.  @lightice11 If I should mark your answer correct, just let me know.

Comment: Ok, too bad you couldn't solve your problem. I recommend posting a question at the parse.com site as the admins seem quite active there. And no, you don't have to mark my answer as correct since it wasn't the right solution.